# JavaScriptSerializer deserialize object "collection" as property in object failing

Tags: javascript, asp.net-ajax, serialization, javascriptserializer

I have a js object structured like:

```
object.property1 = "some string";
object.property2 = "some string";
object.property3.property1 = "some string";
object.property3.property2 = "some string";
object.property3.property2 = "some string";
```

i'm using JSON.stringify(object) to pass this with ajax request. When i try to deserialize this using JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize as a Dictionary i get the following error:

No parameterless constructor defined for type of 'System.String'.

This exact same process is working for regular object with non "collection" properties.. thanks for any help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because the deserializer doesn't know how to handle the sub-object. What you have in JS is this:

```
var x = {
  'property1' : 'string',
  'property2' : 'string',
  'property3' : { p1: 'string', p2: 'string', p3: 'string' },
};
```

which doesn't have a map to something valid in C#:

```
HashTable h = new HashTable();
h.Add("property1", "string");
h.Add("property2", "string");
h.Add("property3", ???);
```

The ??? is because there's no type defined here, so how would the deserializer know what the anonymous object in your JS represents?

**Edit**

There is no way to do what you're trying to accomplish here. You'll need to make your object typed. For example, defining your class like this:

```
class Foo{
  string property1 { get; set; } 
  string property2 { get; set; }
  Bar property3 { get; set; } // "Bar" would describe your sub-object
}

class Bar{
  string p1 { get; set; }
  string p2 { get; set; }
  string p3 { get; set; }
}
```

...or something to that effect.

Comment: This is a great elaboration of my original question.. do you have an answer? thanks!

Comment: ok that makes sense and is easiest enough.. Once i've typed them how i deserialize the whole thing again?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the JavaScriptSerializer, but I'm guessing: Foo foo = JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize<Foo>(incomingJson);

Answer (score 0):

As a more general answer, in my case I had objects that looked like:

```
{ "field1" : "value", "data" : { "foo" : "bar" } }
```

I originally had the data field as a string when it should've been a `Dictionary<string, string>` as specified on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) for objects that use dictionary syntax.

```
public class Message
{
   public string field1 { get; set; }

   public Dictionary<string, string> data { get; set; }
}
```