# Error when passing Model object to my view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created the following model object:-

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Models

    {
        public class listofpack
        {
           public string packageName { get; set; }
           public string packageId { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Which i am populating its value on the controller as follow:-

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
                query["j_username"] = "kermit";
                query["hash"] = "9449B5ABCFA9AFDA36B801351ED3DF66";
                query["loginAs"] = "admin";
                query["loginAs"] = User.Identity.Name;

                var url = new UriBuilder("http://localhost:8080/jw/web/json/workflow/package/list");
                url.Query = query.ToString();
                string json = client.DownloadString(url.ToString());
                var model = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<listofpack>(json);
                return View(model);
                // return Content(json, "application/json");
            }

        }
```

After that on the view i am trying to loop through the model as follow:-

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.Models.listofpack>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
@foreach(var item in Model) { 

        @Html.ActionLink(item.packageId.ToString(), "about", "Home", new { id = "crm"},null)

}
```

but when i run the view i will get the following error:-

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'MvcApplication1.Models.listofpack', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MvcApplication1.Models.listofpack]'.
```

BR

**:::UPDATE::::
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

i have updated the controller code to be:-

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
                query["j_username"] = "kermit";
                query["hash"] = "9449B5ABCFA9AFDA36B801351ED3DF66";
                query["loginAs"] = "admin";
                query["loginAs"] = User.Identity.Name;

                var url = new UriBuilder("http://localhost:8080/jw/web/json/workflow/package/list");
                url.Query = query.ToString();
                string json = client.DownloadString(url.ToString());
                var model = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize <List<listofpack>>(json);
                return View(model);
                            }
            }
```

and on the view:-

```
@model List<MvcApplication1.Models.listofpack>
@Model.Count();
@foreach(var item in Model) { 

        @Html.ActionLink(item.packageId.ToString(), "about", "Home", new { id = "crm"},null)

}
```

But the problem is that nothing will be displayed in the view and the `.count()` will return zero although there should be 5 jason objects passed to the view. So what might be going wrong??
Best Regards

Comment: Read about "Deserialize" method of "JavaScriptSerializer" class:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355316.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
var model = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<listofpack>(json);
```

is deserializing into a single listofpack object.  Your view expects

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.Models.listofpack>
```

maybe try something along this lines:

```
var model = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<IEnumerable<listofpack>>(json);
```

Comment: Using IEnumerable<> will raise the following error :- No parameterless constructor defined for type of 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[MvcApplication1.Models.listofpack, MvcApplication1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'.

Comment: It sounds like your model is null.

Comment: @john G:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386929/no-parameterless-constructor-defined-for-type-of-system-string-during-json-des

Answer (score 0):

Read this question :
[No parameterless constructor defined for type of 'System.String' during JSON deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386929/no-parameterless-constructor-defined-for-type-of-system-string-during-json-des)

```
No parameterless constructor defined for type of 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[MvcApplication1.Models.listofpack, MvcApplication1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'.
```

This exception means that the generic type "IEnumerable< listofpack >" u used doesn't have a constructor because it's an interface,so you should use "Dictionary" or "List"

Edit:
Here's an example:
I created a class and name it Employee:

```
  public class Employee
{    
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
}
```

then i wrote the following statements in the controller :

```
string jsonEmployees="{'employees': [{ 'firstName':'John' , 'lastName':'Doe' }, { 'firstName':'Anna' , 'lastName':'Smith' }, { 'firstName':'Peter' , 'lastName':'Jones' }]}";
var model = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string,List<Employee>>>(jsonEmployees);
return View(model);
```

so try using "Dictionary< string,List< listOfpack >>".