# Fix for no parameterless constructor defined for type of 'System.String[]' during deserialization

Tags: c#, serialization

I'm failing to deserialize a HttpResponseMessage and store the value as a string[].

```
string content = message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
string[] result = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<string[]>(content);
```

I had to change from a deprecated Type t to string[] because the API method signature changed and so now I'm getting an error: *No parameterless constructor defined for type of 'System.String[]'*.

I haven't found the solution to my question online nor on stackoverflow but I've tried to use this method FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(Type) but when I put the right hand value of result within the parentheses I get an error: *cannot convert from 'string[]' to 'System.Type'* which makes sense since I believe that method creates an instance rather than "assists" in deserializing.

How do I correctly get the value from my deserialized HttpResponseMessage as a string[]?

References:

[No parameterless constructor defined for type of 'System.String' during JSON deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386929/no-parameterless-constructor-defined-for-type-of-system-string-during-json-des)

Comment: You could use `List<string>` and then call `ToArray()` on it if you really need an array.

Comment: Is there a reason why this works over the array, maybe because List<T> is actually a type?

Comment: It is because there is a default, parameterless constructor.

Comment: If you'd like reputation for your correct comment please answer the question otherwise I'll answer my own question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Crowcoder mentioned in the comments, the answer to my issue to is to use `List<string>` followed by a call of `.ToArray()`, instead of `string[]` because it contains a default parameterless constructor.

```
string content = message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
List<string> temp = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<string>>(content);
string[] actual = temp.ToArray();
```